# Trying to install Razer device configuration tool

Tags: installation, mouse

It can be found [here.](http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html)

I followed the directions in the readme file but I don't see the application anywhere.

I realize this isn't a lot to go on, I'm new to ubuntu and linux in general. If you need anymore information please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a section in [that link](http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html) called **"Download"**. From there you can download  [razercfg-0.20.tar.bz2](http://bues.ch/razercfg/razercfg-0.20.tar.bz2) package and install it following this post: [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)